# Where to use asterisk in struct type?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I am bit confused on where to use asterisk while using struct type.

What's the difference between `struct node* x` and `struct node *x` ?

Comment: It's a personal preference really.

Comment: Both `struct node* x` and `struct node *x` are same. Normally `*` should used before variable name i.e before `x`.